# TableView displays negative numbers incorrectly

Tags: bugs, visualization, undocumented

I'm  trying to substitute TableForm with TableView because TableView is more handy with big data .

But on my Mathematica 9.0.1 (ubuntu 14.04_64bit) there is a problem with negative numbers:

```
aa = {{5.10, 1.2}, {-5.10, -1.2}}

aa // TableForm
```

the last is fine but if I type

```
aa//TableView
```

the output of negative nuimbers is wrong (see attached immage)
Negative numbers like -5.1 appears like -.51  !!!!

[image]

######## UPDATE 04.06.2014 @ 8.21 GMT

If you work with strings like that:

```
aa1 = {{"5.1", "1.2"}, {"-5.1", "-1.2"}}
```

TableView has no problem, look the picture:

[image]

Comment: The same thing happens here (Mma 9.0.1 on Win32)

Comment: .. same here (MMA 9.0.1.0, Windows 8 64bit)

Comment: Do not forget that `TableView` is undocumented and unsupported.  Bad things may happen if you use it. (In practice: it may crash your front end and you'll lose unsaved changes, as well as the current kernel state. It happened to me.)

Comment: @belisarius I do not agree with the bugs tag you added. I feel that that should only be apllied to MMA features that are part of the official corpus.

Comment: Working like a charm on _v8_ Linux. Picture [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iuF5O.png)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think it may serve others to be aware that the misbehavior has been repro'ed. Of course you can't report this to WRI, but as this isn't an official site, the tag works more as a help/warn for other users than as a request/demand to fix the behavior.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Anyway, feel free to remove it if your comment gets some upvotes

Comment: @belisarius It's a judgment call. I'll await the upvotes...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries would a new tag (say bugs-undocumented) make any sense? I fear rather not...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Isn't it undocumented because they are still _de_ bugging it? :P

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'd appreciate you raising the question of using the `bugs` tag for undocumented functionality on Meta.

Comment: @Yves In accordance with a past Meta question answered by R.M, which I'm too lazy to find, we are using double tagging, e.g. `list-manipulation` *and* `filtering` rather than `list-filtering`, so I have added `undocumented` as appropriate.

Comment: @Öskå in V8 `TableView` was made of boxes such as `GridBox`. In V9 it was reinvented with its own `TableViewBox`. So the V8 and V9 versions are completely different beasts.

Comment: You can goad it into "working" with actual numbers instead of strings with something like `Map[N[Rationalize[#], 3] &, aa, {2}] // TableView`, perhaps replacing the `3` with something that sniffs at actual digits to determine how many to use...

Comment: @rasher, it works...  just using N[Rationalize[aa], 5] // TableView, Thanks

Comment: same problem in 10.0.2

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly a bug, of course.
You may also check the following "reformatting" weird behavior: If after executing `TableView` you "reexecute" the output, the negative numbers get their correct formatting:

[image]

as mentioned in the comments above it looks like a `ToBoxes` bugged implementations for negative numbers. Any of the following work OK:

```
a1 = Map[ToBoxes, aa, {2}]
a2 = Map[ToString, aa, {2}]
a3 = Map[SetPrecision[#, 3] &, aa, {2}]
TableView /@ {aa, a1, a2, a3}
```