# Undocumented TableView function

Tags: list-manipulation, undocumented

Seeking information on undocumented function TableView. *Exempli gratia*,

```
tab=Table[Table[If[Mod[i,Prime[j]]==1,1,0],{i,1,10}],{j,1,2}]
tab//TableView
```

$ $

```
{{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}}
```

[image]

Comment: All that I will say is that it is not finished, its design will change, and will probably crash on you.  But it will be super cool if/when its finished.  :)

Comment: Just to emphasize what @ihojnicki said: it ***will*** crash on you if you try to do serious work with it.

Comment: You don't need double `Table`. `1tab = Table[If[Mod[i, Prime[j]] == 1, 1, 0], {j, 1, 2}, {i, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Evaluate `?? TableView` for `Attributes` and `Options`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Thanks. It's just an example.

Comment: @b3m2a1 For the few doing serious work: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85531) will not crash on you until `TableView` is finished. :)

Comment: @gwr Nice plug :) Unfortunately it's the editability of `TableView` that causes such lovely crashes. But that is a good alternative.

Comment: A piece of information: it is around since at least 2009 ([MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Oct/msg00221.html)), and it had many issues throughout the years ([for example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49016/89)).

Comment: According to the company, it is expected to be released in version 13.

Comment: @RaymondWynne Thanks. Please get enough details to make an 'acceptable' answer, if you can, and put this back as an answer, so I can upvote it.

Comment: It will be marked as experimental soon, so it will be in the docs. That doesn't mean it will not crash on you... :) When will it graduate? IDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally... [`TableView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableView.html) arrives in version 12.1:

[image]

Comment: This is a great start, but deleting entries does not actually delete them when you use the Dynamic expression internally.  It's good for adding stuff, though - just don't make a mistake!  I may make a bug report for this.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 12.0 and the issue of dynamic deleting seems to work fine